# pass parameters of xacro file in another xacro file

Tags: ros-kinetic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this cameras.urdf.xacro file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="origins">
     <link name="$(arg tf_prefix_camera1)_pose_frame"/>
     <link name="$(arg tf_prefix_camera2)_link"/>

     <joint name="$(arg tf_prefix_camera1)_to_$(arg tf_prefix_camera2)" type="fixed">
       <parent link="$(arg tf_prefix_camera1)_pose_frame"/>
       <child link="$(arg tf_prefix_camera2)_link"/>
       <origin xyz="0.009 0.021 0.027" rpy="0.000 -0.018 0.005"/>
     </joint>
</robot>
```

So, this file has parameters tf_prefix_camera1 and tf_prefix_camera2. And i want to include this file in another xacro file and set this parameters. how can i do it?

```
<xacro:include filename="$(find realsense2_camera)/urdf/mount_t265_d435.urdf.xacro tf_prefix_camera1:=t265 tf_prefix_camera2:=d435" />
```

like this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331432/pass-parameters-of-xacro-file-in-another-xacro-file/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are not that far from the correct solution you just need some adjustments :

- Your `cameras.urdf.xacro` should actually use some macros to receive the parameters :

  ```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <robot name="camera" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
     <xacro:macro name="camera" params="tf_prefix_camera1 tf_prefix_camera2">
         <link name="${tf_prefix_camera1}_pose_frame"/>
            <link name="${tf_prefix_camera2}_link"/>

         <joint name="${tf_prefix_camera1)_to_${tf_prefix_camera2)" type="fixed">
              <parent link="${tf_prefix_camera1}_pose_frame"/>
              <child link="${tf_prefix_camera2}_link"/>
           <origin xyz="0.009 0.021 0.027" rpy="0.000 -0.018 0.005"/>
         </joint>
     </xacro:macro>
     </robot>
  ```

The important parts here are `xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro"` to properly use the macro and to define the macro `camera` like a function, i.e. specifying its arguments (here its params).
Note also that it's not like in the launch files, `$(arg ARG)` you just need brackets around the name of your param.

- In your other file you just need :

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <robot name="camera" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
   <xacro:include filename="$(find YOUR_PKG)/urdf/cameras.urdf.xacro"/>
   <camera tf_prefix_camera1="t265" tf_prefix_camera2="d435"/>
   </robot>
  ```

In your example you didn't include `cameras.urdf.xacro` but another urdf file is this a copy/paste mistake ?
To call the macro you have previously defined, you just need a tag with the name of your macro and simply assign a value to your parameters. That will simply copy and paste everything from the `camera.urdf.xacro` file between the `<xacro>` tag (so everything except the 2 first lines and the last one) and replace the paramaters with their value.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1